# Is there any tool to convert stored procedure SQL to string with EscapeConcatenation?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have over 50 stored procedures that I need to convert so that I can use a dynamic whereclause in them. My select statemement looks like this in SQL. I need to change this to a varchar(max) string and use Execute(@SQL) or sp_executesql @SQL

Is there any tool online or purchased that can convert this where clause into the proper string format with the correct escape sequences for the @Parameters?

```
;WITH TempResult AS(SELECT  
        DataDt
        ,EffDt
        ,SettlementDt
        ,BankId
        ,SeqNum
        ,DeleteFlag
        ,LoanNum
        ,BondLoanSaleType
        ,PurchaseProceedsAmt
        ,SettledPrinBal
        ,IntRecMiscAmt
        ,BuydownCashClearingAmt
        ,ARClearingDAPAmt
        ,ARCashClearingAmt
        ,ARSuspenseAmt
        ,ImpoundsSoldLoansAmt
        ,BondCommitmentFeesAmt
        ,SRPAmt
        ,OtherFeeAmt
        ,ActiveFlagBit = case ActiveFlagBit when 1 then 1 else 0 end
        ,UploadByCfcUserId
        ,UploadDtTm
        ,UploadedFileName
        ,ApprovedFlagBit   = case ApprovedFlagBit when 1 then 1 else 0 end
        ,ApproveRejectByCfcUserId
        ,ApproveRejectDtTm
        ,ApprovalTaskId
        ,ArchiveDtTm
  FROM guiUploadBondLoanSales u (nolock)
    WHERE  
        (@LoanList.exist('/NewDataSet/Table1') = 0 or LoanNum in (select LoanNum from #tmpLoan))
        and (@DataDtTo = '01/01/1900' or DataDt between @DataDtFrom and @DataDtTo)
        and (@SettlementDtTo = '01/01/1900' or SettlementDt between @SettlementDtFrom and @SettlementDtTo)
        and (@ShowOnlyLatest = 0 or (ActiveFlagBit = 1 and ApprovedFlagBit = 1 and u.DataDt = 
            (select max(DataDt) from guiUploadBondLoanSales u1 (nolock)
                where u1.LoanNum = u.LoanNum and u1.ActiveFlagBit = 1 and u1.ApprovedFlagBit = 1)))
        and (@TaskId = 0 or ApprovalTaskId = @TaskId)
        and (@FileName = '' or UploadedFileName like '%' + @FileName + '%')
        and (@UploadedByUsers.exist('/NewDataSet/Table1') = 0 or UploadByCfcUserId in (select UploadedByUsers from #UploadedByUsers))
        and (@ApprovedByUsers.exist('/NewDataSet/Table1') = 0 or ApproveRejectByCfcUserId in (select ApprovedByUsers from #ApprovedByUsers))
        and (@UploadDtTo = '01/01/1900' or UploadDtTm between @UploadDtFrom and @UploadDtTo)
        and (@ApprovedDtTo = '01/01/1900' or ApproveRejectDtTm between @ApprovedDtFrom and @ApprovedDtTo)
        and (@HideArchive = 0 or u.ArchiveDtTm = '1/1/1900' )
    ), TempCount AS (  SELECT COUNT(*) AS MaxRows FROM TempResult) SELECT *, TempCount.MaxRows FROM TempResult, TempCount ORDER BY TempResult.UploadDtTm    OFFSET @OFFSET ROWS FETCH NEXT @FETCH ROWS ONLY OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: Using such [catch-all queries](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlinthewild/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/) are a bad idea that typically result in bad performance. Using dynamic SQL will negate any benefit you'd get from a stored procedure. BTW that `NOLOCK` suggests the query already has performance problems that will only get *worse* by `NOLOCK`. NOLOCK doesn't mean "don't take locks", it means `read dirty data while taking even more locks`

Comment: Here are three excellent articles on the topic of catch all queries. https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/ and http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlinthewild/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/ and http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html. I agree with the perils of NOLOCK. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Yes I agree on the no lock. That is one of the things I have to modify with these stored procedures too. As far as catch all queries what do you suggest that would be better than what is being done?

Comment: Check out the three articles I linked above.